# Space of continuous functions with compact support dense in space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

How can we prove that the space of continuous functions with compact support is dense in the space of continuous functions that vanish at infinity?

Comment: Please show some effort in your questions. You have asked 3 questions in the space of 20 minutes all without any effort or courtesy.

Comment: This question is by no means off-topic (though I think it has nothing to do with functional analysis. Neither does it have to hold in metric space (LCH is ok)). I also think the question was very clearly presented (one sentence is enough). Maybe there is duplication because a user mentioned that above. I also agree that it is not good if the asker showed no effort. But it is unreasonable to close this question under an incorrect reason. As for the answer to this question, it is Proposition 4.35 in P132 of text "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications" by Gerald B. Folland, ...

Comment: ... proved in LCH.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably your norm is the maximum absolute distance at any point. If I give you a continuous $f$ that vanishes at $\infty$ and an $\epsilon \gt 0$, you need to find a continuous $g$ with compact support that is everywhere within $\epsilon$ of $f$. Since $f$ vanishes at $\infty$, there is some $N$ such that $f(x) \lt \epsilon/2$ whenever $ x \gt N$. So if $g=f$ out to $N$, drops quickly to $0$ and stays there...

Added:  We are trying to show that any continuous function that vanishes at infinity can be approximated closely (within $\epsilon$) by a function with compact support.  The range where $f$ is large (greater that $\epsilon/2$) is some interval $(M,N)$  Our approximating function will agree with $f$ over that range.  We then know that $|f(x)| \lt \epsilon/2$ on $(\infty,M)$ and $(N,\infty)$.  If we let the approximating function go to zero on $(M',M)$ and $(N,N')$ and be zero on $(-infty,M')$ and $(N',\infty)$ it will have compact support and be within $\epsilon$ of $f$ over the whole line.

Comment: If the domain is not the space of real numbers then how to maintain continuity of the function.

Comment: What is your domain and range?  When I saw compact support and vanish at infinity I thought $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, but it works in $\Bbb C$ as well.

Comment: If I take domain X to be any topological space and the space of all continuous real valued functions on X  with compact support with sup norm. Then, what will be its completion and how ?

Comment: The same approach works as long as you have a similar concept of "go to zero at infinity". You need to have the function value to be forced to be small as long as it is "big enough".  Of course, if $X$ is compact, you don't have this concept, but functions with compact support are not so special then.

Comment: Could you explain this again? I am confused about the N that you need.

Comment: @TylerHilton:  see if this helps

Comment: Will $g$ still be in the set of functions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$ when $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in [-N,N]$?

Comment: @Kurome:  you are right, if $f=0$ at a point then the $g$ I defined would not have compact support.  It can be fixed by defining $g$ to be slightly nonzero.

Comment: Could you confirm that result does not hold in general, but only on LCH spaces?

Answer (score -2):

In other words: Let me denote by $C_c$ the space of continuous function with compact support and $C_0$ the one of continuous function vanishing at infinity.

> $C_c$ dense in $C_0$ if and only if $\forall g \in C_0$ it exists a sequence $g_n\in C_c$ s.t. $g_n\to g$ w.r.t. the supremum-norm

So we can define 
\begin{equation}
g_N(x)=g(x) \text{ for } \vert x\vert\leq N \text{ and } g_N(x)=0 \text{ if } \vert x\vert>N
\end{equation}
So $g_N$ is compactly supported. 
Thus $\lim_{N\to \infty} \Vert g_N-g\Vert_{\infty}=0$

Comment: Your $g_N$ are not continuous.