# How to generalize Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem from $C_c(X)$ to $C_0(X)$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

I'm reading about Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem from [this](http://www.hellenicaworld.com/Science/Mathematics/en/RieszMarkovKakutaniReptheorem.html) page.

---

Let

- $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
- $C_c(X)$ the space of continuous compactly supported complex-valued functions on $X$.
- $C_0(X)$ the space of continuous functions on $X$ which vanish at infinity.

A non-negative Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ is called *regular* if and only if

- $\mu(K)<\infty$ for every compact $K$;
- For every Borel set $E$, $\mu(E)=\inf \{\mu(U) \mid E \subseteq U, U \text { open}\}$.
- The relation $\mu(E)=\sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq E, K \text { compact}\}$
  holds whenever $E$ is open, or when $E$ is Borel and $\mu(E)<\infty$.

A complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ is called *regular* if the non-negative measure $|\mu|$ is regular as defined above.

- **Theorem 1:**  For any positive linear functional $\psi$ on $C_c(X)$, there is a unique regular non-negative Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that
  $$
  \forall f \in C_{c}(X): \quad \psi(f)=\int_{X} f \mathrm d \mu.
  $$
- **Theorem 2:** For any continuous linear functional $\psi$ on $C_0(X)$, there is a unique regular complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathrm{X}$ such that
  $$
  \forall f \in C_{0}(X): \quad \psi(f)=\int_{X} f \mathrm  d \mu
  $$
  The operator norm of $\psi$ is the total variation of $\mu$, i.e., $\|\psi\|=|\mu|(X)$. Finally, $\psi$ is positive if and only if $\mu$ is non-negative.

---

Then there is a paragraph

> One can deduce **Theorem 2** about linear functionals from the **Theorem 1** about positive linear functionals by first showing that a bounded linear functional can be written as a finite linear combination of positive ones.

I know that

- Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then the space of continuous functions with *compact support* is dense in that of continuous functions *vanishing at infinity* w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_\infty$. [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465216/space-of-continuous-functions-with-compact-support-dense-in-space-of-continuous#comment7850246_465216).

but could not figure out how to infer **Theorem 2** from **Theorem 1**. Could you elaborate on this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\psi$ is a  continuous linear functional on $C_0(X)$ its restriction to $C_c(X)$ is a continuous linear functional. Hence, there exits $\mu$ as in Theorem 1 with $\psi (f)=\int fd\mu$ for all $f \in C_c(X)$. All that remains it to show that the equation holds for all $f \in C_0(X)$. [The norm of $\psi$ is equal to the norm of its restriction to $C_c(X)$ since $C_c(X)$  is dense in $C_0(X)$].
If $f \in C_0(X)$ then there is a sequence $(f_n)$ in $C_c(X))$ with $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Since $\psi (f_n)=\int f_nd\mu$ for all $n$ we can take limit as $n \to \infty$ to finish the proof. [Recall that $|\int [f_n-f]d\mu|\leq \|f_n-f\|_{\infty} d|\mu|$].

Comment: Don't you need $\psi$ to be positive to apply Theorem 1 directly?